# Area between two triangles/squares/pentagons (Polygon ring)

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, area

**Introduction**
During a class we got this mathematical problem: Calculate the area of a ring, formed by 2 concentric circles, knowing that the outer circle chord is 10 cm, and it is tangent to the inner circle. Here is a drawing:[image: Two concentric circles]

Link to someone else who shared this problem: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-calculate-the-area-of-a-ring-formed-by-2-concentric-circles-knowing-that-the-outer-circle-chord-is-long-10-cm-and-it-is-tangent-to-the-inner-circle

**The main problem, area of the polygon ring**
After solving it my teacher wanted me to extend this issue to triangles, squares or pentagons. I then asked where the chord would be and he didn't want to tell me. After working on this for quite a while I'm none the wiser. Do anyone have a clue on how one could find the area between these figures using only a "chord" of 10 cm without anything else given? [image: Examples of these areas]

He mentioned something about having the "chord" go through one of the lines of the inner square in the square case, but I didn't quite understand how.

**Solved for a special case**
After Jean Marie's hint I tried drawing a line through the diagonal of the chord and another through on of the vertices at 45 degrees. Only the latter gave me something meaningful to work on. I've managed to find the area of a special case where the  "chord" is 8 units since the intersection points of the chord and the outer square then meet. When the chord is 8 units the intersection points meet and enables the pythagorean theorem to be applied.
[image]
This is also true for a triangle as long as the intersection points meet, but it is a particular case and far from general.

**Solved for the general square case by YNK**
YNK managed to find the area between two squares by using the inscribed circles of these squares. From this construction the lengths of the small and large square is 2r and 2R respectively. The chord is given as 10 cm. The area between the squares would then be (2R)^2 - (2r)^2 which can be written as 4(R^2-r^2). We substitute R^2-r^2 by 5^2 from the original problem, and the area between them turns out to 4*25=100 square cm.
[image: Illustration of this square case]

**Current problem, the general case for triangles or pentagons**
The problem now remains to study whether or not this method of only using a chord of 10 cm to find the areas betweem figures works for triangles and pentagons. I tried to do the same for a triangle, but no success yet.
[image: The triangle case with inscribed circles].
[image: The triangle case with circumcircles]

Thanks for all the help so far everyone! :)

Comment: It's vague but I think extending one side of a smaller polygon can produce such "chord".

Comment: For the case of the square, a choice that would be natural is to consider a chord at 45°

Comment: @JeanMarie Would that chord at 45 degrees be at one of the vertices or the diagonal of the smaller square?

Comment: Yes, it's what I meant.

Comment: @JeanMarie I've updated the post with your idea. I managed to solve a special case, but still no answer for a general case. Did I understand you idea correctly by the way?

Comment: Your nice figure (with the redish squares) is very particular.  Indeed, if we denote by $2R$ and $2r$ the respective sides of the big and small squares (by analogy with notations for circles): you have assumed in this figure that $r=R/2$ which is a very particular case. In the general case, the chord passing through one of the vertices with a 45° slope doesn't intersect the sides of the big square in their middle.

Comment: The beauty if the chord-in-ring problem is that the ring area only depends on the length of the chord, so any ring with a chord of that length has the same area. This is not the case with other shapes. With a polygon ring, if the chord touches an inner vertex and connects two adjacent outer edges, then you can lengthen all the edges without affecting the chord, and so increase the ring area while keeping the chord constant. So in such a case you will need to know one extra piece of information, such as the size of one of the shapes.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Indeed that seems to be my conclusion as well. After applying what I could from the case of the chord in a ring problem I've managed to get this formula for the area between the shapes: A = 2(R^2 + 5^2) or A = 2(r^2+50) where these are the radiuses of the circle within the larger square, or the radius of the circle through the smaller square. It seems the radius or length of either square has to be given in order to find the area.

Comment: Did you try this for two given concentric squares? Draw the two inscribed circles of the two squares. Then draw a chord of the larger circle that is tangent to the smaller circle. Let the length of this chord be $\large{\pmb{a}}$. As you already know, the area of the annulus of the two circles is equal to $0.25a^2\pi$. Now, the area between the two squares (@JaapScherphuis called it polygon ring) is equal to $a^2$, i.e. the area depends only on the length of this particular chord. This could be the chord your teacher did not reveal to you.

Comment: @YNK Very nice. You turned it back to the original problem with circles so that the chord length is sufficient for the annulus area, and then used the fact that the areas of a regular polygon and its inscribed circle are in a fixed ratio independent of their size.

Comment: @YNK That is simply brilliant. I will update this question with that tomorrow. I guess I forgot about the inscribed circles and only focused on the surrounding circles. I wonder if this method will hold for triangles, pentagons or even further...

Comment: Yes, it does hold for for both isosceles triangles and regular pentagons alike. In the case of triangles, the area in question is equal to $\dfrac{3\sqrt{3}}{4}a^2$. You can also use  circumcircles of given figures in place of the incircles to obtain a chord, the squared length of which is directly proportional to the area of polygon rings.

Comment: @YNK I still can't seem to figure it out for triangles. I've added the triangles with inscribed circles and circumcircles at the bottom of this question. In both cases it seems as if I have to adjust the triangle size to perfectly fit with the circles, making it a particular case again. Even so, for the circumcircle example, I can't find a way to express the height of the inner triangle, only the outer triangle (R+r). How did you get the answer for the area for the polygon ring of triangles, and the squared length?

Comment: @YNK Very well, sorry for being so demanding. To quote Mason & Davis: _"A problem is something that gets inside you, it nags and 'wants' to be resolved"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: PolygonAnnulus]

In this answer, we hope to analyse the n-gon to show that the area of a polygon ring created by placing a smaller regular polygon with $n \left(\ge 3\right)$ sides completely inside a larger regular polygon having the same number of sides. We also assume without loss of generality that the centers of the two polygons coincide at $O$.

The diagrams shows a part of the polygon under investigation. Please pay your attention to $\mathrm{Fig.\space 1}$. Let the sidelengths of the two polygons be $b$ and $kb$, where $k\gt1$. The radii of the inscribed circles of the two polygons are $r_{\text{i}}$ and $R_{\text{i}}$. The chord of the larger incircle is a tangent to the smaller incircle at $K$ and it has the length $c_{\text{i}}$. The line segment $ON$ is drawn perpendicular to the sides $A_1A_2$ and $\bar{A_1}\bar{A_2}$ to make $M$ and $N$ are their midpoints respectively. We also have,
$$\theta=\dfrac{\pi}{n}.\tag{0}$$

Considering the two right-angled triangles $A_1MO$ and $\bar{A_1}NO$, we can write,
$$r_{\text{i}}=\dfrac{b}{2}\cot\left(\theta\right) \qquad\text{and}\qquad R_{\text{i}}=\dfrac{kb}{2}\cot\left(\theta\right).\tag{1}$$

Using (1) we can express the area of the polygon ring $A$ as,
$$A=\dfrac{nkb R_{\text{i}}}{2}-\dfrac{nb r_{\text{i}}}{2}=\dfrac{nb^2}{4}\left(k^2-1\right) \cot\left(\theta\right).\tag{2}$$

An expression for $c_{\text{i}}$ can derived using the right-angled triangle $POK$ as shown below.
$$ c_{\text{i}}=2\sqrt{R_{\text{i}}^2- r_{\text{i}}^2} = b\sqrt{k^2-1}\cot\left(\theta\right)\tag{3}$$

By substituting (0) and (3) in (2), we can obtain a formula for $A$ in terms of $c_{\text{i}}$ and $n$.
$$A=\dfrac{n}{4}\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{n}\right) c_{\text{i}}^2\tag{4}$$

According to (4), the area of the polygon ring depends only on the number of sides and the length of the chord $PQ$.

We kindly request you to go through this text to see whether the description given there answers your question. We hope to supplement this answer by providing some more details a few hours from now. In the mean time you can try to derive an expression for the area of a n-gon ring using the circumcircles.